# Как передать значение c checkbox angular?

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular5, angular10

В компоненте есть переменная типа boolean - isBlocked, и на форме имею два checkbox , хочу что б при нажатии на один присваивалось значение true переменной isBlocked, а при нажатии на другой присваивалось значение false  переменной isBlocked. Можно это как то реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="doBlock(false)"/>
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="doBlock(true)"/>
</div>
```

ts:

```js
export class C {
    private isBlocked = false;
    doBlock(value: boolean): void {
        this.isBlocked = value;
    }
}
```